# Image Converter not working in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Im using the converter to change the image but image is not loading here can somebody please help me here what I'm done wrong? I had checked the converter by debugging it is not getting hit.

Converter Code:

```
public class DownloadIconConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return ((bool)value) ? "progressicon.png" : "cloud_download.png";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

In Xaml

```
  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <converter:DownloadIconConverter x:Key="downloadiconconverter" />
</ContentPage.Resources>

  <ImageButton
                                HeightRequest="40"  
                                    IsVisible="True"

                                Source="{Binding DownloadIcon,Converter={StaticResource downloadiconconverter}}"
                                WidthRequest="35" Command ="{Binding BindingContext.Download, Source={x:Reference listview}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
```

In Code behind file

```
    public bool DownloadIcon
    {
        get { return downloadicon; }
        set { SetProperty(ref downloadicon, value); }
    }
```

Comment: I see something funny going on with the `BindingContext`. Where exactly is the `DownloadIcon` property located? And to what do you set the `BindingContext` property of your page? I think you're trying to look in two different places.

Comment: another area to check is where your images are stored especially in the android project. I have found if matters whether they are in drawable or mipmap folders

Comment: @GeraldVersluis DownloadIcon property locViewModelhe ViewModel of the page,   wishey code_-->without using the converter the image is loaded fine.

Comment: Inorder to see check if you are binding right thing, put a breakpoint to `Convert` method. If hits you have a problem at resource location, else you have problem with binding.

Comment: Its not hitting but what is the problem in binding??

Comment: can somebody help please

Comment: Are you using a ListView or a View that involves DataTemplates?

Comment: Hi @G.hakim, yes

Comment: And is this boolean in your model or in your ViewModel?

Comment: Boolean in ViewModel

Comment: Hi @G.hakim, For more details you can refer this also 
                                            
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/150124/image-converter-not-working-in-data-template/p1?new=1

Comment: Hello @Suriya I have added an answer take a look

Comment: Hi @G.hakim,Thanks it works fine

Comment: Hi @G.hakim, can you give me email id? .I need to discuss few things regarding xamarin.

Comment: Hi @G.hakim, But I don't need to navigate to another page when I tapped in gesture.How to fix this?

Comment: You can contact me on LinkedIn which is available in my profile. If the answer works for you kindly mark it as correct.`But I don't need to navigate to another page when I tapped in gesture. How to fix this?`-You will have to check the code in your download command for this

Comment: @Suriya my personal email id is hakimgulamali88@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

The Binding in my knowledge is not working because the boolean is in the ViewModel and not accessible to the listview data template

Try using this:

```
 Source="{Binding BindingContext.DownloadIcon, Converter={StaticResource downloadiconconverter},Source={x:Reference listview}}"
```